# ORDER BY Clause on part of a column value

Tags: java, sql-order-by, ormlite

I want to implement `ORDER BY` clause in ORMLite on a part value of column. I tried a lot but could not find a way. So can any tell how can achieve this? In my table there is a column START_DATE in which date value is in format `YYYY-mm-DD` I want order by on DD value.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you must first figure out how to do it in raw SQL which is very database dependent.  If your database can do this, there is a [`QueryBuilder.orderByRaw(...)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#orderByRaw(java.lang.String)) that you can use.  For example, in MySQL you should be able to do the following where `START_DATE` is a field in your entity.

```
queryBuilder.orderByRaw("Month(START_DATE)");
```

Hope this helps.